# mavenLocal() functionality alternatives

Tags: gradle

`mavenLocal(`) currently serve my need by searching at my local m2 for my dev builds.

Is there other way to tell gradle to search for local m2 without changing build.gradle or other source code file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Initialization Scripts.

> There are several ways to use an init script:
>
> Specify a file on the command line. The command line option is -I or
>   --init-script followed by the path to the script. The command line option can appear more than once, each time adding another init
>   script.
>
> Put a file called init.gradle in the USER_HOME/.gradle/ directory.
>
> Put a file that ends with .gradle in the USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/
>   directory.
>
> Put a file that ends with .gradle in the GRADLE_HOME/init.d/
>   directory, in the Gradle distribution. This allows you to package up a
>   custom Gradle distribution containing some custom build logic and
>   plugins. You can combine this with the Gradle wrapper as a way to make
>   custom logic available to all builds in your enterprise.

Example init script

```
initscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Check out [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html?_ga=2.99146587.43900636.1521217079-929657946.1513880959) for details.